# ASP.NET Core Mvc: tag helper `asp-for-model`?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC, when using `asp-for` tag helper on `input` fields, you have to add property name:

```
@model Person

<input asp-for="FirstName" />
```

Is there tag helper like `asp-for-model`?

```
@model Enum

<input asp-for-model />
```

`asp-for=""` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag helpers can evaluate expressions in the argument. For example:

```
asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"
```

So for the model:

```
@model Enum

<input asp-for="@Model" />
```