# How do I pass the entire model using ASP.NET Core's Anchor Tag Helper?

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I pass the model using the [Anchor Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for a `[HttpPost]` method?

I tried using the `<input asp-for="@model">`:

```cs
<div class="list-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <a asp-asp-controller="PostModels" asp-action="Create" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="@item.ID">@item.Title @item.EventDate</a><br />
        <span>@item.Line1</span>
        <input asp-for="@item" />
    }
</div>
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773721/22019322

But that calls the `[HttpGet]` method in my controller:

```cs
// GET: PostModels/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new PostModel();
    return View(model);
}

// POST: PostModels/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Title,Posted,EventDate,Line1,Image1,Line2,Image2,Line3,Image3")] PostModel postModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Add(postModel);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(postModel);
}
```

### How do I pass the entire **Model** in the **Anchor Tag**?

*EDIT add PostModel*:

```cs
public class PostModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Image1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Image2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Image3 { get; set; }
    public Guid ResetToken { get; set; }
}
```

When I have a Post open to edit, I want to pass the whole model to the controller to save instead of passing each property of the model individually.

Comment: What do you want to do? Could you please describe it a little bit? Also what properties postmodel has?

Comment: @OzanBAYRAM - edited the question with answers for you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the model details.

I did not get the logic that behind your needs. Let me explain problems that you are having.

First you are using a link and an input field in foreach. This will just create a html for link and input with item object name text.
You may check the created html result from your browser with "view page source" option.

When you click the link, it will not post anything. You will just initiate a new get request. For that reason, you are falling in to the get handler. (If have your data as query string you may still get them from the get handler by defining them as method parameters. Of if the names in query string matches to your model properties model binder may bind them.)

Second, to pass some data on post from view to controller, you need to create a form and submit values which are form elements of the form. For instance, if you have a input type text with the name of "somevalue" this value can be bind to your post method and can be read as string value.

You may post value like this:

```
<form id="sampleform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="samplevalue" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And you may get the value like this:

```
public void OnPost(string samplevalue)
{

}
```

You may apply this logic to your code.

Also, you may check this full working sample.
https://github.com/okutbay/MongoHead/blob/master/MongoHeadSample/Pages/People/Form.cshtml.cs

Here is the working sample:
http://mongohead.okb.io/people

I advise you to check this site. It has all you need.
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/

Comment: Yes, the main page shows a list of IEnumerable<PostModel> items. Clicking an item should open the details in a bootstrap modal popup. Saving the popup should pass the entire model.

Comment: using link to show modal popup a little tricky. Please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347786/html-anchor-tag-with-javascript-onclick-event